# Extract part of a string in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

[image: this is what the string looks like]

String:
"Department=Acc:2";"Classes=Accessoire";"Suppliers=xxx23";"Category=Décor";"Discount=no";Related_Carousel_Products=[23043]";"Accessory Type=Crinolines et Shorts";

My excel cells are filled with data like this and I want to extract a specific part of it, for example I would like to extract Accessory Type="Crinoline" into a new column so that I can edit them separately. I've tried this article it has many creative ways to extract the data but I cannot find a way to extract in the way I want, I want to extract part of the string, including the quotes.

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3639-excel-extract-part-of-string.html

Comment: Try explore `MID(a,b,c)` ... with b coming from `FIND("Accessory Type=",..,1)` ..

Comment: What does "whole part of the string" even mean?  Sure would make it easier to understand if you actually showed an example of what you want to extract.  Also please show what you tried and how it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***UPDATED** - screenshot showing breakdown of each key function*

You can do this using mid + search as follows (screenshot below/[this](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j963JaWYyslIffbam9?e=6anvFQ) sheet refer):

```
=MID(B2,SEARCH($F$2,B2),SEARCH(";",MID(B2,SEARCH($F$2,B2)+1,LEN(B2))))
```

where:

- B2: the raw text
- F2 = 'Accessory Type' (or any other thing you specify that satisfies final bullet)
- Entire string you want to return (with or without quotation marks) falls after 'Accessory Type' and before the very next semi-colon (;) - per your example/below screenshot/above link.

[image: Screenshot]

**How does this work?**

1. We need to find the part of text that starts with the selected word(s) (e.g. "*Accessory Type*" in this case) and ends after the description of that accessory type (in this case, it's made up "*asdfhadhgk*")
2. Working from inside out mid function (A) returns everything *after* the words "Accessory Type"
3. Great, now we just need to it 'stop' a bit sooner, i.e. after the semi-colon that first appears after the words Accessory.  This is exactly what the outer Mid function (D) achieves (it returns the string starting with "Accessory Type" up to the semi colon)

*Screenshots below refer.*

[image: Breakdown by function]

[image: Table summary]

Comment: Thank you very much It is gonna save me so much time!! I have no clue how the formula works tho, I do know the MID formula but could you please explain us what is goin on in there? :)

Comment: @Anurag so take it apart and work out what each bit does - best way to learn.

Comment: @Anurag - hope the update helps.  Let me know otherwise.

Comment: @JB-007 Really appreciate it thanks:) It actually helped. Just one other issue tho, I have another field called "Accessory by Age=xxxx" but when I use the above formula, It does not work. I get Null value error, what could be the reason for this? I am sure those fields are there in the provided cell. I just noticed it is because in some cases, Accessory by Age comes in the last part of the string, there is no semicolon there to look for. How do I get around this?

Comment: Ahhh - no semi colon.  We need to know at what point we should cut off the mid internal mid statement.  E.g. after a certain number of characters or what - so, for instance, in your  "Accessory by Age=xxxx", I imagine the 'xxxx' are all digits - we could use s space character as the cut-off; e.g. 'space after equals sign' - but are there instances where age 'xxxx' is not followed by a space (if so, issue becomes  little stickier (sticky but not impossible) - can you extract a couple of examples and we can look at a couple of examples in the comment section here?

Comment: @JB-007 I was able to fix it by just concatenating a semi colon at the end of the search string.  It's all perfect now thanks :)

Comment: Cool - glad to hear.